# My node.js http request worked for the first time and now it is showing some error

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, getaddrinfo

I am using node.js 'request' module for making http request. This code worked for the first time. But now it shows some error.

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body); 
} else {
    console.log(error);
}
})
```

Error:

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com]
 code: 'ENOTFOUND',
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'www.google.com' }
```

I cannot understand why this is happening. My internet works fine and I can open google.com in my browser.

Comment: it's working proper,what @version you are using for request module

Comment: I am using request module v2.65.0 and node v0.12.7.

Comment: @ Aphro Knight I checked it with request@2.65.0(same as yours) & node@0.10.26, it's working proper for me

Answer (score 1):

It's a DNS issue. You could try explicitly using Google's DNS by doing:

```
require('dns').setServers(['8.8.8.8','8.8.4.4']);
```

Then perform your request.